# Hack Rust Visibility and Privacy

Tags: rust, class-visibility

I tried to use a `struct` from an external crate which does not use the `pub` key.

I guess the best fix will be to open a PR but my curiosity get triggered here.

In C++ it is pretty easy. We can do:

```cpp
#define private public
#include <...> // import public as public AND also private as public
#undef private
```

This will trick the compiler while parsing the code, so we get access to all the methods/fields of the class.

Any idea for Rust?

Here is a concrete example:

```rust
use warp::{
    compression::{Compression, internal::CompressionProps},
    reply::Response,
};

pub enum CompressionAlgorithms {
    Brotli(Compression<dyn Fn(CompressionProps) -> Response>),
    Deflate(Compression<dyn Fn(CompressionProps) -> Response>),
    Gzip(Compression<dyn Fn(CompressionProps) -> Response>),
}
```

Compile error: `` error[E0603]: module `internal` is private `` - in this example, we are trying to import a module and not a structure... Not sure if it changes anything.

Unfortunately, [the docs for error E0603](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0603) is not really helpful if we do not own the crate. Same for [the docs on visibility and privacy in the Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea for Rust?

If a crate does not expose something, then that thing is not for you to use. It might be an oversight, or it might be a design decision, that is immaterial.

> Compile error: error[E0603]: module `internal` is private - in this example, we are trying to import a module and not a structure... Not sure if it changes anything.

No. Hell, the naming scheme is literally telling you that the private module is *internal details*, it couldn't be any clearer that this is very much not intended for you to touch. [`CompressionProps` was specifically made non-public](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/pull/472#pullrequestreview-371467585).

Comment: Yeah, the example is maybe not perfect. In fact my question is more a challenge to find a way to bypass the Rust compiler class-visibility... Even if it is a dirty and unsafe hack which ignore any design decision.

Comment: Well, you always can just clone the crate sources, modify them and use the local copy as dependency, if you're not going to publish your crate yourself. Aside from that - no, there's no way to modify source code of the dependency from the dependent.

Comment: Which is, in fact, is what `#include` does. It expands to entire contents of the included file.

Comment: Which is also why C++ compilers have to keep re-parsing the same files over and over and over again and [chromium starts with 12 million LOCs but by the time it's done the compiler has gone through 3.6 billion LOCs](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/03/30/big-project-build-times-chromium/).

Comment: @Cerberus Would you like to make that into an answer? It really is the only way to do what the OP is asking for.